# Convert Javascript Object to Array of Objects to use in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javascript-objects

I am migrating d3 to newer version 7.6.1, now the version which i am using is 5.15 and it has one method which is **d3.entries** and in version 7.6.1 it is deprecated.

As far as i know this d3.entries is used to convert object to array of object for example -

```
chart.data = function(value,newName,newColor,sorted) {
       varColor=newColor;
       varSorted=sorted;
       displayData = d3.entries(value); //version 5.15
       console.log("-----");
       console.log(displayData);
       assignedName = newName;
       return chart;
}
```

```
{Metrics: 404, Asset: 492, B7: 84} to [{'Metrics',404},  {'Asset': 492}, {'B7': 84}]
```

but when i upgrade my d3 version this d3.entries() function is not there so i used **Object.entries()** -

```
chart.data = function(value,newName,newColor,sorted) {
       varColor=newColor;
       varSorted=sorted;
       displayData = Object.entries(value); //version 7.6
       console.log("-----");
       console.log(displayData);
       assignedName = newName;
       return chart;
}
```

```
My Output is - 
[['Metrics',404],  ['Asset': 492], ['B7': 84]]
```

but still i am not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```js
Array.from(Object.entries(value) , d=>{
  return{
    d[0] : d[1]
  }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
let obj = {Metrics: 404, Asset: 492, B7: 84};

let arr = []

for(let item in obj){
  arr.push({[item]:obj[item]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain js

```
const displayData = Object.keys(rendered_data).map(k => ({
    key: k,
    value: rendered_data[k],
  }));
```